# How can I remove my last commit in my local git repository

Tags: git

When I do a 'git pull', I have conflict with the head commit. So I did a 'git rebase --abort'

Can I 'save' my commit to a "patch" and then do a git pull?

What I want to emulate is:

- I did not commit, but I did a 'git stash' instead
- Do a git pull to avoid any merge error

So I need somehow to 'turn back the clock'. Is that possible with git?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Your `7826b2` patch will still cause a conflict when it's applied after pulling, but you can do the following:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
git stash
git pull
git stash pop # Will cause a conflict
git commit    # Re-commit 7826b2
```

Another workflow is also possible:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
git pull
git cherry-pick 7826b2 # Will cause a conflict
```

The second workflow relies on the fact that Git keeps the `7826b2` commit in the reflog (you can think of it as the recycle bin) even though you reset the changes it introduced with the first line.

Answer (score 8):

If you did commit your changes in your local repository, you could do a straight rebase:

> git fetch origin
>
> git rebase origin/master

This unwinds your local commits from the local master, applies new commits from origin/master, and then replays your local commits.

In your situation, this will result in a conflict and git will tell you which files need to be edited to resolve the conflict. After you do so, `git add` those files and then `git commit` with no arguments to recommit the changes.

Answer (score 3):

First I suggest to do a backup of your branch:

```
git branch your_branch_backup
```

Then the easiest way is:

```
git reset --soft <commit> #Go back in time but without loosing your changes
git stash                 #Stash your changes
git pull                  #Refresh your branch with origin
git stash pop             #Re-apply your changes on the refreshed branch
```

Then you can commit as usual

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, in fact in git, I'm sure there's a multitude of ways of doing it...

You could do:

```
git stash     # Stash your changes
git pull      # Pull the changes
git stash pop # Pop your stash
```

You could do:

```
git pull --rebase # Bring in the changes and apply yours on top of it.
```

You could do:

```
git stash     # Stash your changes
git checkout <commit> # Pull a specific commit.
git stash pop # Pop your stash
```

Hope it helps.